# C++ Arrays in a Beginner Application

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to write a program that allows the user to enter 12 double values representing store sales for each month of one year. After all 12 values are entered, I need to display each month’s sales amount and a message indicating whether it is higher, lower, or equal to the average month’s sales amount. I can get the program to list the month by number and average the sales, but I am unable to get it to list the months by NAME and as well as compare each month to the average and display whether it is higher, lower, or equal to the average amount. I've looked through the forums here and at cplusplus.com but am not getting anywhere. I'm not looking for finished code, but any advice is appreciated. My code:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   const int MONTHLY_SALES = 12;
   const char month[12] = {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'};
   double totalSales = 0;
   double storeSales[12];
   double AVERAGE;
   int x;
   for(x = 0; x < MONTHLY_SALES; ++x)
   {
      cout << "Enter the sales for month #" << (x + 1) << " "; 
      cin >> storeSales[x];
   }

   cout << endl << "The sales for each month are:" << endl;
   for(x = 0; x < MONTHLY_SALES; ++x)
   {
      totalSales += storeSales[x];
      cout << storeSales[x] << "  ";
   }
   cout << endl;
   AVERAGE = totalSales / MONTHLY_SALES;
   cout << "The average sales is " << AVERAGE << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Show what you have tried for listing the month and comparing them.

Comment: For `C++` you should instead consider using `std::array<std::string, 12>` and `std::array<double, 12>`.

Comment: Is there something not working?

Comment: Are you sure `const char month[12]` is right? If you don't use C++ data types shouldn't it be `const char* month[12]` and then use `"Jan"` instead of `'Jan'` (i.e., notice the difference in the type of quotes).

Comment: I'm sorry, I must not have been clear. I can't figure out how to reference the months against each other. Also, I'm very new to C++, so I don't yet know what std::array... even means.

Comment: @haldav If you're interested in learning C++ then you should look at the data structures it provides (e.g., [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) and use them otherwise you're more on a track to learn C (i.e., C++ and C are not the same language).

Comment: @haldav [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). It's a lot of mumbo jumbo which can be hard to understand, I know, but scroll to the bottom for examples and it might be more clear how you can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your compiler should not have let you get away with that definition of `month`.  You need to declare the array as `const char*` and use double quotes, since these are strings:

```
const char *month[12] = {"Jan", "Feb",    ...    , "Dec" };
```

You can then get the month name using `month[x]` where `x` is an integer between 0 and 11.

As for the averages, something simple like this in another loop:

```
int diff = storeSales[x] - AVERAGE;
if( diff < 0.0 ) {
    // below average
} else if( diff > 0.0 ) {
    // above average
} else {
    // equal
}
```

Bear in mind also that you are dealing with `double` values, so in some cases an average that appears to be the same value (rounded) as something else might in fact be above or below.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually tried the `month[x]`, but I must have missed using a pointer. I'll try it and see how it goes.

Comment: why not use `string` instead of `const char*`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `const string`.  Still, there's no point in declaring a constant array like this using dynamic allocation provided by `string`.  A table of string literals is perfectly well represented by `const char *`.  Unless you want to use them as `string` later in the code, they should remain as literals.